# Open as many terminals as the number of ssh-s logged out and close the terminals in which ssh-s where logged out

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

There are several terminals in a single localhost in which I have ssh-ed into the same user and same IP address. I want to find all the terminals in which a remote host has been logged, terminate all processes running in those and log out of that remote host. I succeeded using the following shell script.

```
#Find list of terminals in which the remote host is logged in.
openedTerminals=`ssh $user@$publicIP "ps -aux | grep -i $user@pts | grep -v grep | cut -d' ' -f 3"`

#close all the ssh sessions to that remote host
i=1
terminalPID=`echo $openedTerminals | cut -d' ' -f $i`
while [[ -n "$terminalPID" ]]
do
    ssh $user@$publicIP "kill $terminalPID"
    i=`expr $i + 1`
    terminalPID=`echo $openedTerminals | cut -d' ' -f $i`
done
```

I used the following command to open a new terminal and ssh into a remote host which worked fine when executed from the command prompt:

`gnome-terminal -window-with-profile=NOCLOSEPROFILE -e "ssh -X $user@$publicIP"`

Apart from doing the work of the 1st code, I want to open a new terminal (by ssh-ing into another remote machine) for every remote machine which was terminated by the 1st code. So I tried to insert the above command in the 1st code as:

```
#Find list of terminals in which the remote host is logged in.
openedTerminals=`ssh $user@$publicIP "ps -aux | grep -i $user@pts | grep -v grep | cut -d' ' -f 3"`

#close all the ssh sessions to that remote host
i=1
terminalPID=`echo $openedTerminals | cut -d' ' -f $i`
while [[ -n "$terminalPID" ]]
do
    ssh $user@$publicIP "kill $terminalPID"
    gnome-terminal -window-with-profile=NOCLOSEPROFILE -e "ssh -X $newUser@$newPublicIP"
    i=`expr $i + 1`
    terminalPID=`echo $openedTerminals | cut -d' ' -f $i`
done
```

But this starts running in an infinite loop and opens infinite number of new terminals.

Please tell me where I am wrong and suggest a way to correct it in order to get the desired solution.

Also, I wish to add a command in the same shell script (1st code) to close the terminals in which the remote machine was logged out. Can anyone please guide me on this?

Thanks in advance,
Saeya

Answer (score 0):

When only one terminal which is ssh-ed to the remote machine is opened, this runs in an infinite loop because of the "cut" command. If there is a separate case to handle one terminal this will work fine.